# Wacom Tablet: is Intuos more easy to use than Intuos Pro?

Tags: drawing-tablet, wacom

Struggling to choose between **Wacom** **Intuos** and **Intuos Pro**:

Somehow, the **non-Pro** tablet visually looks nicer to work with -
I like it's M size is more compact than **Pro** M size, 
and especially I feel like the dotted area on the **non-Pro** can help to be precise in some working issues.

I am not an illustrator or an artist, though I am working with vectors and retouching. I also work a lot in MS Word () and PPT.

A comfortable work is more important than a budget, so am I weird to think that **non-Pro** will be more easy for me to use?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If the price is right significantly lower, I think I'd go with the non-pro model. There's not much to regret about that purchase. Not as many buttons (you'll likely use keyboard anyways. The touch ring in pro is cool though.). No pen tilt (Doesn't matter). No eraser tip (Doesn't matter). No wireless (Rotating the device itself is super disorientating, you won't be doing that. The convenience level is similar to a wireless keyboard. Wireless accessory kit can be bought separately. ) You won't be missing the touch features if you don't have them and I don't think you would use them much anyways.

Answer (score 3):

We had a non-pro Intuos M for less than a year now and were very happy with its ease of use, and the precision by which we could enter data with the pressure-sensitive pen. It is a very good value for money digitizing tablet for the occasional or semi-professional usage. We do recommend it.

#### but...

After less than a year we still made the switch to the Pro version simply because of the many additional features it has:

- twice the resolution of both, the tablet, and the pressure levels
- eraser function on the pen
- tilt-recognition in addition to pressure
- a much thinner design that makes drawing more comfortable
- pen with a more ergonomic grip to it and with a solid base it can rest on

In addition the pro tablet has many options that don't come to mind at first. It is wireless (Bluetooth), has multi-touch gesture recognition, is upgradeable e.g. with a paper-holder (think of your grid lines!), or can have different surfaces with a different roughness to them. The latter also gives us the possibility to  replace the surface when it is worn out after a while. All other replacement parts appear to be much easier to get too, be it a replacement pen, or pen-tips. Most shops sadly have these for the Pro version only.

We feel that the silghtly larger dimensions are more than compensated by the thinner tablet, and by the base for the pen (that otherwise always was somewhere else).

We also don't miss the grid at all because when drawing you keep your eyes on the monitor anyway. If you need a grid, then consider the paper-version.

If however budget matters then if you don't actually use it for drawing but simply for a mouse replacement, and to see how much you may need the tablet at all you will be happy with the non-pro version too. Some features of the Pro version may also need the approproate software to support them (we use Gimp).

Comment: Thanks. Is it true that non-pro has a cheap feeling of its material and pen? 
Do you often use a  pro multi-touch feature and if non-pro is comfortable for zooming? 
Also, is pro M-size easy for everyday carrying?

Comment: The pen but not the tablet indeed feels a little bit "cheaper" - but only in direct comparison. As said we were always happy with it. Once you get used to the multi-touch it can save some time but depending on your painting style it may also interfere with you drawing - for us multi-touch was not a criterion.